# VB NET - Query Mysql - where is \

Tags: mysql, vb.net, double, slash

I have this code for find in mysql.

```
Try
    MysqlConn.Close()
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "select id from foto where path = '" & TextBox5.Text & "'"
    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    While READER.Read
        Dim sName = READER.GetString("id")
        TextBox6.Text = sName
    End While
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    MysqlConn.Dispose()
End Try
```

But the bad what i want is like `C:\my pic\myfile.jpg` (TextBox5.Text) and mysql dont found it. But if i try like `C:\\my pic\\myfile.jpg` it's ok. How i do to had a `\\` (double slash) in my query ?

Thanks for the help..........

Comment: are you asking how do you programmatically add a / if only 1 / ?

Comment: Instead of creating your query from unchecked TextBox input, you should use a Parameter ... or else [Moms will pwn your app](https://xkcd.com/327/). As for your problem: Just `TextBox5.Text.Replace("\\", "\\\\")` should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks Filburt.... I try in few hours...

Comment: I posted an answer, as @Filburt suggestion, will likely fix the issue.

Comment: @JimmySmith I wasn't sure about how MySqlCommand Parameters handle escaping so I didn't post.

Comment: MySQL might get treated differently... so I found this little gem and updated my answer!  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString("\some data here\")

Comment: I removed my answer so @Filburt can post his and get the credit.  I see no reason to downvote my answer.

Comment: @JimmySmith Didn't DV but waited to UV until final edit. Pity you deleted because it solved the OPs issue AND showed Command Parameter usage. I have no intention whatsoever to compete with your answer. My comment just meant to hint on possible reasons for DV (from others).

Comment: @JimmySmith Flagged to un-delete.

Comment: @Filburt sorry had a moment there.  I've undeleted my answer, and changed the text as you were right.  Something with this site that irritates me is no one has to provide a reason to downvote and it seems like they just do it to troll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString() method.

```
Try
    MysqlConn.Close()
    MysqlConn.Open()
    Dim Query As String
    Query = "select id from foto where path = @PATH"
    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
    COMMAND.AddWithValue("@PATH",MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString(Textbox5.Text))
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    While READER.Read
        Dim sName = READER.GetString("id")
        TextBox6.Text = sName
    End While
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
    MysqlConn.Dispose()
End Try
```

Comment: glad that helped solve the issue.  @Filburt thanks for the help also.